# Palantir Workbook - Looping through a Dataset and Creating a New Dataset with Python (or SQL)

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, palantir-foundry

I'm using a Palantir Workbook to build a new dataset from existing ones. One of them has between 1 and 10 rows per patient. My goal is to loop through each patient row and apply logic to identify duplicate rows with different details or determine the status based on previous rows. Ultimately, I want to output the final result to a new dataset and then move on to the next patient row(s).

As an MS SQL Developer new to Palantir (Spark SQL/Python), I'm struggling to find the right approach. My initial thought was to use Python code, but I'm having trouble finding working scripts to iterate through the rows. However, I'm open to alternative solutions, such as using some type of cursor in SQL if it's more suitable.

Could someone kindly provide a small example of code or guidance on how to loop through a dataset in a Palantir Workbook and generate a new dataset as the output?

I tried to just get a very basic start using the following script I found:

```
def unnamed_2(SourceDataSet):
    import pandas as pandas

    patient_icn_values = []

    for index, row in SourceDataSet.iterrows():
        patient_icn_values.append(row['patient_icn'])

    my_output = pd.DataFrame({'patient_icn': patient_icn_values})

    return my_output

    new_dataset = unnamed_2(SourceDataSet)
```

This is the error:

> Missing transform attribute
>
> A DataFrame object does not have an attribute iterrows. Please check the spelling and/or the datatype of the object.

Comment: A couple clarifying questions: (1) are you looking to output one new dataset per patient? Or just one single dataset for all patients? I'm assuming the latter, but your phrasing makes it a little ambiguous. (2) it sounds like you're trying to accomplish two things: deduplicating rows and, separate but possibly related, creating or updating some "status" value based on previous rows (ordered by, e.g., date). Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your exact situation & needs, my initial reaction is to suggest to avoid iteration over rows and instead try built-in pyspark capabilities. The Foundry docs have [a couple paragraphs that touch on this](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/pyspark-coming-from-python/index.html#coming-from-python).

Here's some code examples you can run in Code Workbooks that might be helpful for deduplicating and computing new values based on a subset of the data (e.g. each patient). I've included the example data at the bottom, which you can upload to Foundry as a dataset and then use in your Workbook. You can see the example outputs in the Logs tab:

```html
def deduplicate_data(notional_patient_example):
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    from pyspark.sql import Window as W

    ####################
    # Check the Logs tab to see the output from the examples
    ####################

    input_df = notional_patient_example

    # https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates.html
    print("Dropping duplicate rows, taking into consideration only select columns")
    input_df.dropDuplicates(["patient_id", "visit_ts", "procedure_name"]).show()

    print(
        "Dropping duplicate rows, taking into consideration only select columns + some new column we compute (in this case, I'm just getting the month but you could imagine something more complicated here)"
    )
    input_df.withColumn("visit_month", F.month("visit_ts")).dropDuplicates(
        ["patient_id", "visit_month", "provider_name"]
    ).show()

    # https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html
    # https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/pyspark-window/index.html
    print(
        "Computing a new value based on the order of patient visits for a single patient. You could then dropDuplicates based on this new value."
    )
    window = (
        W()
        .partitionBy("patient_id")
        .orderBy("visit_ts")
        .rowsBetween(W.currentRow, W.unboundedFollowing)
    )
    input_df.withColumn(
        "is_latest_visit", F.max("visit_ts").over(window) == F.col("visit_ts")
    ).show()

    print(
        "Or, you could find potential bad data by filtering to patients that have two 'most recent visits'. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to do this for Patient 3 who had an invalid procedure_Y on 2023-07-22."
    )
    input_df.withColumn(
        "is_latest_visit", F.max("visit_ts").over(window) == F.col("visit_ts")
    ).withColumn(
        "has_multiple_latest_visits",
        F.sum(F.col("is_latest_visit").cast("integer")).over(window) > 1,
    ).filter(
        F.col("has_multiple_latest_visits") == True
    ).show()

    # Just to show how to output a dataset
    output_df = input_df.dropDuplicates(["patient_id", "visit_ts", "procedure_name"])
    return output_df
```

| patient_id | visit_ts | patient_name | procedure_name | provider_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19-Jul | A | procedure_1 | Dr. E |
| 1 | 19-Jul | A | procedure_2 | Dr. F |
| 1 | 21-Jul | A | procedure_3 | Dr. G |
| 1 | 21-Jul | A | procedure_3 | Dr. G |
| 2 | 19-Jul | B | procedure_2 | Dr. H |
| 2 | 20-Jul | B | procedure_2 | Dr. H |
| 2 | 21-Jul | B | procedure_5 | Dr. J |
| 2 | 22-Jul | B | procedure_3 | Dr. G |
| 2 | 23-Jul | B | procedure_3 | Dr. F |
| 3 | 22-Jul | C | procedure_Y | Dr. J |
| 3 | 23-Jul | C | procedure_4 | Dr. F |
| 4 | 19-Jul | D | procedure_5 | Dr. H |
| 4 | 20-Jul | D | procedure_5 | Dr. J |
| 4 | 21-Jul | D | procedure_5 | Dr. G |
| 4 | 22-Jul | D | procedure_2 | Dr. J |
| 4 | 23-Jul | D | procedure_1 | Dr. E |

Comment: The Foundry doc link was very enlightening!  You managed to tie several things together for me in this post.  As for the final result...this might work but I have more to learn.

Comment: Great! And for anyone else reading this, those couple paragraphs in the docs are not specific to Foundry -- they could generalize to any system that uses pyspark.

Comment: I'm actually working with immunization records to build a profile for each patient.  Initial shot, dt, mfr, complete, dt, mfr, boost 1, dt...boost 2, dt...etc.

I's more like a pivot of the data but I don't have all immunization data.  Some shots could have happened at a local drug store etc.  So I have to fill in the blanks I can and make assumptions like...if boosted then they must have been vaccinated.

I'll have to look at more than one field to determine which shot and then write to different columns once I know which record I'm working with.

Comment: That sounds like a lot more work than the example I provided, but conceptually similar: use a window to isolate rows for a given patient, apply some logic to derive a new column, keep that new column value or use it in another window function, rinse/repeat. I deal with the complexity of tasks like this by having many nodes on the code workbook graph where each node is some discrete bit of logic. This results in a lot of joins, but when I'm satisfied with the end result I can go back and consolidate everything. Messy graph is easier for me than dense transforms, at least for iteration.